# Why does CultureTableRecord throw an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception, cultureinfo, culture

I am getting a NullReferenceException when a String is being compared.  This is only happening for one customer, but on several computers at his location.  We can't reproduce this internally.

Here's is a partial stack trace of the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(Int32 cultureId, Boolean useUserOverride)
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureByLCIDOrName(Int32 preferLCID, String fallbackToString)  
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InitUserDefaultCulture()
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_UserDefaultCulture()
at System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentCulture()
at System.String.Equals(String value, StringComparison comparisonType)
```

What can cause the CultureTableRecord to become corrupt?

---

EDIT:
Here's the method that is calling String.Equals.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as MyObject;
    return other != null && this.FileName.Equals(other.FileName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Would be better to see your work as well. Read: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please provide the code and the line no. where exactly the error is throwing so we can help. only error will not help to solve problem.